# using arrays from one file in nested functions in another file

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP file which contains associative arrays. I have them all in one file for ease of editing/updating. For example:

```
$ass_first = array(      "title"=>"Title",
                            "first_name"=>"First Name",
                            "surname"=>"Surname",
                            "phone"=>"Phone Number",
                            "email"=>"Email Address",
                            "add1"=>"House Name/Number",
                            "add2"=>"Street",
                            "add3"=>"Town",
                            "add4"=>"City",
                            "add5"=>"Post Code"
                            );
```

In another file, I have functions which are passed variables, which in turn call other functions.

For example I have a function which is called to create a table containing form inputs. Inside this function, there is a test to see what form input is needed and the necessary function is called.

```
function create_table($titles, $id) { //$titles is the relevant array from lists.php, $id is the id of the containing div

    $select = array('timescale','bus_route','train_stat');  //'select' id list

foreach ($titles as $k=>$v) { //$k is the database/id/name $v is the description text
    if (in_array($k,$select)){
        select_box($k,$v);
    }
    else if //input is a text area
        text_box($k,$v);
    }
    else{ //input is a checkbox
        check_box($k,$v);
    }
}
```

}

Inside these three 'nestled functions' I want to refer to some arrays contained in the lists.php file.

I want to know the best way to add these arrays to the functions scope. I have been told variable variables arent neccessarily the best way to go, neither is declaring global variables. I cant think of any other way to do it!

Also passing them as a variable into the functions isnt really an option because the three different nestled functions need a different set of arrays meaning three sets of arrays will be passed but only one would be used at any one time!

Comment: Why are you passing the functions as variables?  What determines if the input is a select/text/checkbox?

Comment: please see the update to the select section of code. Basically if the name of the input is in the 'select' array, then the 'create select input' function is called. But apart from the $k and $v values being passed I also need access to other arrays, which havent been passed to the function

Comment: @BrianAdams I could do, but id prefer to keep all the arrays in one separate file so its easier to update and keep track of. Im just after the best way to refer to these arrays from a different file.

Comment: I misread your question, you aren't passing the functions as variables.  So if you don't want to use a global variable and you don't want to pass the arrays to create_table as a variable, the only other option I can think of is `require 'lists.php';` inside your create_table function.

Comment: ahhhh!!! I didnt know you could do the require/include commands inside the function - I presumed it just had to be at the top of the main PHP file! Passing the arrays is no good - but what is peoples issue with global variables? Ive seen plenty of comments on SO that urge people not to use them - but i dont see why!

Comment: It can make it difficult to debug later, you have to take the time to track down where the global variable was set.

Comment: ok that makes sense, although my arrays will always just be used as read-only, so it wont be an issue in this case. I think your suggestion is the way to go! Feel free to convert it to an answer for reps! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the arrays to your create_table function:

```
function create_table($titles, $id, $arrays) {
    ...
}
```

You can go ahead and use a global variable, maybe add a comment above it saying what file sets the variable:

```
function create_table($titles, $id) {
    //$arrays gets set in lists.php
    global $arrays;
    ...
}
```

Or you can require your lists.php file like so:

```
function create_table($titles, $id) {
    require 'lists.php';
    ...
}
```

Comment: I still dont see what peoples issue is with global! Its fairly easy to  keep track of whats setting it from where, and if the array is needed in various different places your going to have that problem whether you use any of your three methods right?